# POST method WEBDAV not run

Tags: http, webdav

I had a server install WEBDAV and I try to do any WEBDAV method
all method like `copy, delete, get, lock, mkcol, propfind, propatch` run good.
I can create file and store data in server with PUT method. But I don't know how to do it in POST.

1. when I post anydata to exist file server return data of old file.
   And I check in server this file not change any thing
2. when I try to post new file it return "The requested URL - URL of
   file - was not found on this server."
3. when I try to post new file with out full path, I just send to
       folder where I want to store file. I hope server create file with
           auto gen Name of file and return name for me. But server return the
           resource content in folder ( some thing like index.html )

### **I want to know how to implement POST method, it can create or repair file on WEBDAV server. any one can help me ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, WebDAV servers do not support POST (more precisely: the WEBDAV specification doesn't mandate any specific behavior for POST, so servers vary in what they do).

Comment: I don't know why in a lot of document talk about webdav post to collection. But I try more times, POST never success :( thanks you